# JdbcSQLException for a grails app with h2 database?

Tags: grails, jdbc, h2

I'm getting a JdbcSQLException whenever I try to deploy my app to a server, though running locally works fine. I have no idea what this error is and can't seem to find the answer on google.

Code throwing the error:

```
class ResultService {

    def recentStoryRuns() {
        StoryRun.list(sort: "batch.dateCreated", order: "desc")
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "STORY_RUN" not found; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id3_1_, this_.version as version3_1_, this_.batch_id as batch3_3_1_, this_.batch_iteration as batch4_3_1_, this_.browser_string as browser5_3_1_, this_.easybresult_id as easybres6_3_1_, this_.failed_scenarios as failed7_3_1_, this_.last_parse_error as last8_3_1_, this_.passed_scenarios as passed9_3_1_, this_.result_parsed_story_status as result10_3_1_, this_.status as status3_1_, this_.story as story3_1_, this_.total_scenarios as total13_3_1_, this_.xml as xml3_1_, storyrunba1_.id as id2_0_, storyrunba1_.version as version2_0_, storyrunba1_.batch_id as batch3_2_0_, storyrunba1_.browsers_string as browsers4_2_0_, storyrunba1_.date_created as date5_2_0_, storyrunba1_.iterations as iterations2_0_, storyrunba1_.site_profile as site7_2_0_, storyrunba1_.stories_string as stories8_2_0_ from story_run this_ inner join story_run_batch storyrunba1_ on this_.batch_id=storyrunba1_.id order by storyrunba1_.date_created desc [42102-164]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4753)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1080)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1686)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1793)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1680)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1523)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1511)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1121)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
        at kindlingtests.ResultService.recentStoryRuns(ResultService.groovy:6)
        at kindlingtests.HomeService.results(HomeService.groovy:19)
        at kindlingtests.ModelFields$_closure1.doCall(ModelFields.groovy:13)
        at kindlingtests.ModelFields.<init>(ModelFields.groovy:12)
        at kindlingtests.HomeService.setControllerModelFields(HomeService.groovy:9)
        at kindlingtests.HomeService.setControllerModelFields(HomeService.groovy:8)
        at kindlingtests.HomeController.index(HomeController.groovy:14)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

[edit]

As requested, my DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your table "STORY_RUN" not exists. Can you post your DataSource.groovy?

Comment: That seems to be the case, but I can't think of a reason why the "STORY_RUN" table would not exist while everything else works fine. Either way, posted my DataSource.groovy file.

Comment: It's an in-memory database, so the schema has to be created at startup, probably by a script. Is this happening in your production environment?

Comment: `dbCreate = "update"` should create missing tables. Check for errors in the logs, I think for some reason the table could not be created.

Comment: @Richard yes, only happens in production, not in development. I will see if I can reproduce the error in prod by using `dbCreate="create-drop"` but like Sergio said, `dbCreate="update"` _should_ create missing tables.

Comment: Tested with `dbCreate="create-drop"` but the issue popped up again.

Comment: What happens if you use a regular persisted database instead of an in-memory database? For example using `jdbc:h2:/data/prodDb;MVCC=TRUE` (that is, using an absolute path).